# Proof of convergence of $a_n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ with $n = 1, 2, ...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = e \approx 2.718...$ but I'm having trouble understanding a step in my book on analysis.

The (existence) proof entails showing that $(a_n)$ is both monotonically increasing and bounded from above. The binomial theorem is first used on $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ to give

$$a_n = \sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r}$$

and

$$a_{n+1} = \sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{r}\frac{1}{(n+1)^r}.$$

The difference of these is then

$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \left[\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n+1}{r}\frac{1}{(n+1)^r} - \binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r}\right] + \frac{1}{(n+1)^{n+1}}.$$

Now, we see that
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r} &= \frac{n(n-1)...(n-r+1)}{r!n^r}\\
                          &= \frac{1}{r!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left( 1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) ...\left( 1 - \frac{r-1}{n}\right)
\end{align}

and similarly for $\binom{n+1}{r}\frac{1}{(n+1)^r}$ (with $n$ replaced by $n+1$ of course) and that each factor $\left(1 - \frac{i}{n+1}\right)$ is greater than $\left(1 - \frac{i}{n}\right)$ and hence $a_{n+1} > a_n$. My issue is as follows; the book continues to deduce that,

> ...since each $1 - \frac{i}{n}$ is less than $1$, we have that $$a_n < \sum_{r=0}^n\frac{1}{r!} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

and that, since it is clear that $r! \geq 2^{r-1}$ for $r \geq 2$, we must have that

> $$a_n < 1 + \sum_{r=0}^n 2^{r-1} < 1 + \frac{1}{1 - (1/2)}=3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

I'm not sure about steps $(1)$ and $(2)$, if anyone could explain the logic to me that'd be grand!

Comment: $p_n(x) = (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$, $p_n'(x) = p_{n-1}(x)$ therefore $\frac{p_n'(x)}{p_n(x)} = 1+\frac{x}{n}$ so that $\frac{p_n'(x)}{p_n(x)}$ converges uniformly to $1$ on $|x| < A$. Integrating you get $ \ln p_n(x) - \ln p_n(0) = \int_0^x \frac{p_n'(t)}{p_n(t)} dt  \to \int_0^x dt = x$ uniformly on $|x| < A$. Since $p_n(0) = 1$ you got that $\ln p_n(x) \to x$ uniformly and $p_n(x) \to e^x$ uniformly (on $|x| < A$)

Comment: and what is cool is that my proof works the same with $p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Comment: @user1952009: It may be a cool proof, but it doesn't answer the question!

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for your proof. Unfortunately I'm not well-versed enough in analysis to have understood it.

Comment: @Ed_4434 just wanted to show you $\frac{p_n'(x)}{p_n(x)} \to 1$, and this is the derivative of $\ln p_n(x)$, and it works the same with $p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k/k!$ (and I made a mistake : $\frac{p_n'(x)}{p_n(x)} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step (1):  From the first line, 
$$a_n = \sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r}$$
From the fourth line
$$\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r} = \frac{1}{r!} \prod\left( 1-\frac{i}{n}\right)$$
Take that expression and sum in and you get assertion (1).

Step (2): The auther breaks up the sum in (1) -- the $1$ represents $r=0$, the remaining sum should have been fromm $r=1$ to $n$, and he should have stated that $r! \geq 2^{r-1}$ for $r\geq 1$.  That step should have read
$$
a_n \leq 1 + \sum_{r=1}^n 2^{1-r} < 1+ \sum_{r=1}^\infty 2^{1-r} = 1+2 = 3
$$

Comment: So there is a typo in the book? I kept thinking $r! \geq 2^{r-1}$ so... $\frac{1}{r!} \leq 2^{r-1}$??

Comment: Yes, there is a typo in the book (or in your question).

Comment: @TonyK There's a PDF listing the errata in the textbook and this was indeed one of them

Answer (score 1):

1. They're saying that for any $r$ we have
   $$
   \binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r} =  \frac{1}{r!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left( 1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) ...\left( 1 - \frac{r-1}{n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{r!}
   $$
   and since $a_n = \sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r}$, that specifically means that $a_n \leq \sum_{r = 0}^n\frac1{r!}$.
2. They're saying (reinterpreted by me) that as long as $r \geq 1$, we have $\frac{1}{r!} \leq \frac 1{2^{r-1}}$, so specifically, 
   $$
   \sum_{r = 0}^n\frac1{r!} = 1 + \sum_{r = 1}^n\frac{1}{r!} \leq 1+\sum_{r = 1}^n\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}\\
    = 1 + \sum_{r = 0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^r}\\
   \leq 1 + \sum_{r = 0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^r}\\
   = 1 + \frac{1}{1-\frac12} = 3
   $$
   where the second line is a change of index for simplicity of reading, and the third line is adding in a bunch of positive terms for simplicity of calculation.

Comment: Is line $(2)$ a typo then? Because it's written $$1 + \sum_{r=0}^n 2^{r-1}$$ (I mean in the question, to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 1):

(1)

You know that it is $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$ and
$$a_n = \sum_{r=0}^n\frac{1}{r!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left( 1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) ...\left( 1 - \frac{r-1}{n}\right)
$$ 
for $n\ge 2$. We have 
$1 - \frac{1}{n}<1$, ..., $1 - \frac{r-1}{n}<1$

and therefore $\frac{1}{r!}\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left( 1 - \frac{2}{n}\right) ...\left( 1 - \frac{r-1}{n}\right)<\frac{1}{r!}$

and it follows $a_n \le \sum\limits_{r=0}^n\frac{1}{r!}$

(2)

It's $\frac{1}{r!}\le \frac{1}{2^{r-1}}$.
Therefore we have $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n\frac{1}{r!}\le 1+1+\sum\limits_{r=2}^n\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}=3$

Answer (score 1):

I like to do these as trains going in opposite directions colliding. You have

$$a_n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$ Let us throw in

$$b_n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}.$$

A little work is still required, but $a_n$ begins low and increases, while $b_n$ begins high and decreases; they crash into each other at the limit.

Since both are strict monotonic, we actually have, for any indices $m,n \geq 1,$
$$ b_m > a_n $$
$$ a_n = 2, \; 2.25, \; 2.370, \; 2.441, \; 2.488, \; 2.521, \;$$
$$ b_n = 4, \;  3.375, \; 3.160, \;  3.051, \; 2.986, \; 2.941, $$

Comment: Will note this down for future exercises!

Comment: @Ed_4434 a similar one, different limit: $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{3} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{n} - \log n,$ while $b_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{3} + \cdots +  \frac{1}{n} - \log (n+1).$ This time $a_n$ starts high and decreases, while $b_n$ starts low and increases.

Answer (score 0):

I provide you an alternative proof.

**Step 1.** The sequence is increasing by the AM-GM inequality.

$$ 1\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \leq \left[\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+n\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right]^{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}.$$
**Step 2.** If $a>b>0$, we have 
$$   (n+1)(a-b)b^{n}\leq (a^{n+1}-b^{n+1})\leq (n+1)(a-b)a^{n}.$$
**Step 3.**  Given $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, we may prove through (Step 2.) that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded,
 hence converging to its supremum.

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}a_{n+1}-a_n &=& \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-\frac{n}{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\\&=&\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}-\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\right]\\(\text{Step 2.})\qquad&\leq&\frac{a_n}{n}-(n+1)\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\\&=&\frac{a_n}{n}-\frac{(n+1)a_{n+1}}{n(n+2)}\end{eqnarray*} $$
Rearranging we get:
$$ (n^2+3n+1)a_{n+1} \leq (n^2+3n+2 )a_n $$
or:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}}\leq 1+\frac{1}{n(n+3)}. $$
Since the product $\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n(n+3)}\right)$ is converging, $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded.
We may also use the AM-GM inequality to prove that
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{n+1} $$
then state that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded since the product $\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{n+1}$ is converging.